# Wizard Control: UploadFile is not keeping its data when I go to a different step

Tags: .net, asp.net, file-upload, wizard

I'using a Wizard web control. All other controls are keeping their data across steps. But UploadFile is the only control taht's not keeping its data when I go to a different step unlike the other controls, such as the texbox.

Yet, I need to keep the data alive because, after the user uploads the image, he needs to see the image along with the rest of the info before clicking the submit button.

Also, if, for some reasons (ex. he wants to change the picture), he can go back and upload something else.

So how do I do that?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Asp.net file upload doesn't keep the file after post-back. I came across similar situation. What i did was,
01.Add a asp.net image control next to upload control.
02.Upload the file to the server folder once user selects a file in upload control.
03.Set the proper server path to asp.net image control.
04.This gives more user friendly when you navigate back and forth using wizard.
05.If user selects another image, repeat step 02 and 03.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

asp.net don`t keep the data of the file after postback...
You need to handle it yourself or use a 3d party like jquery plaugin (search for "uploadify" in google for example) that fire event on the server when uploading file, that let you save the file or whatever you want to do with it.